# Query filter by value in meta_value array

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, query, advanced-custom-fields

I try to add a filter to make an elementor post widget displays the posts depending on a certain custom field.

The custom field key is `adress` and contains an array with some keys like street_number, street_name, city, post_code etc.

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/filterByPostCode', function( $query ) {
    
    if ('field' === $_GET['getby']) {
        
        $meta_query = $query->get('meta_query');

        if (!$meta_query) {
            $meta_query = [];
        }
        
        $meta_query[] = [
            'key' => 'adress',
            'value' => [ 
                'key' => 'post_code',
                'value' => $_GET['field'],
                'compare' => '='
            ],
        ];

        $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
    }

});
```

What will be the correct query ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55354/how-can-i-create-a-meta-query-with-an-array-as-meta-field). The query is simply :

```
        $meta_query[] = [
            'key' => 'adresse',
            'value' => $_GET['field'],
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ];
```

As it will search into the serialized (2D) array of the key `adress` in the table post_meta from the DB any occurence of my `$_GET['field']` value. That means it will also search into every key name and its value, but that's enough for me.