# Meta_query with key as an array

Tags: meta-value

I facing a problem with a meta_query where the meta_key's value can have multiple dates :

My meta field `event_dates` can have several dates like : 20220902,20220928

**CODE EXPECTED :**

```
$today = date( "Ymd");

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'event_dates',
            'value'     => $today,
            'compare'   => '>='
        )
    )
);
```

With the help of other wpse's questions like [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55354/how-can-i-create-a-meta-query-with-an-array-as-meta-field), I've try things like :

```
  ...
  'value'     =>  serialize( intval( $today ) ),
  ...

  // AND/OR
  // in the ACF admin field ("event_dates")
  a:1:{i:0;i:20220902;i:1;i:20220928;}

  // OR 
  20220902,20220928
```

I also try like a post I can't find again said :

```
foreach($event_dates as $dates) :

    add_post_meta( $inserted_id, 'event_dates', $dates );

endforeach;
```

**My goal is to find posts where in this meta field (at least) one of those dates is older than today.**

Some help please !! :)

Comment: you can't use `event_dates` for ordering if it's storing a string of serialised PHP, the values have to be numbers, and singular ( not inside an array or list ). I don't know if ACF will let you store them that way but that's an ACF problem and 3rd party plugin/ACF questions are offtopic here. The most you could hope for is a semi-reliable contains to test for the existence of the data as a filter, but you can never order or use logic conditions such as `>=` on serialised data

Comment: In fact they are store are number ie : 20221012

Comment: and it shows that in the database if you look at the raw value instead of using PHP to check? Not `a:1:{i:0;i:20220902;i:1;i:20220928;}`? And it is _only_ 1 number, not a comma separated list? If there are multiple values stored in the same meta value then it is a serialised data structure, it's just serialised as a CSV instead of PHP, you should not store structured data in post meta if you plan to query/order/sort by it, wether that's something simple like a list, or complicated such as objects/JSON/XML/etc